# Opening Files in Photoshop with Applescript

Tags: automation, applescript, photoshop

I am trying to use Applescript to automate a task in photoshop.

When attempting to open a file:

```
tell application "Adobe Photoshop CS5"

 -- Open the first image
 set filePath to alias "Users:jameshale:Pictures:DSC_1273.jpg"
 with timeout of 5 seconds
  open filePath as Camera RAW
 end timeout

end tell
```

The result is an error:

```
error "Adobe Photoshop CS5 got an error: Can’t get alias \"Users:jameshale:Pictures:DSC_1273.jpg\"." number -1728
```

What am I doing wrong?

-J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alias path includes the HD name in the root.  So you need to change your one line to this

```
// Replace Macintosh HD with your HD name 
set filePath to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:jameshale:Pictures:DSC_1273.jpg"
```